# Getting error on editing content types: /admin/structure/menu/parents 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: nodes, javascript, users

I'm getting errors on editing any content type. Chrome tools reveals that one of them is as follows:

```
POST http://mysite.local/admin/structure/menu/parents 403 (Forbidden) jquery.js?v=1.4.4:142
c.extend.ajax jquery.js?v=1.4.4:142
Drupal.menu_update_parent_list menu.admin.js?mv8h6q:27
(anonymous function) article:101636
(anonymous function)
```

I tried this but no change: https://drupal.org/node/1633130

I'm wondering if this pertains more to jquery than anything else. Any thoughts?

Comment: What UID are you when you're editing the content type?

Comment: I'm not logged in as user 1, but figured I didn't need to be for this. In fact, I tried the patch per the article listed above, but it makes no difference, although it makes sense. Also, the site appears to drag now. The only thing that's changed is we went from PHP 5.2.27 to PHP 5.3.19, and actually tried newer versions as well. Any thoughts?